# How to add radio button back into form in Rails App if user had previously selected it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my rails app, I'm trying to make sure that the option saved to the database for a user (in a radio button question) is present in the list of radio button options, even if it is no longer part of the list. For example, I may have at one point had the following list of options:

```
Option A
Option B
Option C
Option D
```

And the user had previously selected "Option D" and that is what is stored in the database.

But now, the list of options has been changed to:

```
Option A
Option B
Option C
```

When the user views his selection, it will now appear as if there is nothing saved in the database for the user. I would like to include Option D on the list only if the user has previously selected it and it's stored in the database for the user, and make sure not to duplicate any existing radio buttons. What's the best way to handle this?

This is what my code currently looks like for that list:

```
<div class="col-6 col-sm-4">
  <div class="org-container">
    <%= f.radio_button :organization_name, "Option A" %>
    <%= f.label :organization_name, :value => "Option A" do %>
      <img src="<%= path_to_logo %>" class="logo">
      <div class="org-label">Option A</div>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="col-6 col-sm-4">
  <div class="org-container">
    <%= f.radio_button :organization_name, "Option B" %>
    <%= f.label :organization_name, :value => "Option B" do %>
      <img src="<%= path_to_logo %>" class="logo">
      <div class="org-label">Option B</div>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="col-6 col-sm-4">
  <div class="org-container">
    <%= f.radio_button :organization_name, "Option C" %>
    <%= f.label :organization_name, :value => "Option C" do %>
      <img src="<%= path_to_logo %>" class="logo">
      <div class="org-label">Option C</div>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: 1. How do you know D is saved?
2. How do you know A, B, C are not saved?
3. How do you know A is not duplicated with B and C?

Comment: Use the answer for above questions to write a `if-else` that wraps around the block displaying D radio button